# When an Active Directory User Logs in to Local Windows 2012 Server Launch a Virtual Machine; Possible?

Tags: active-directory, virtual-machines, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services

I won't get into the reasons why this needs to happen, however, is this possible.

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 box that needs to be used as a daily driver for a few of a clients employees.

Ideal scenario:

An employee sits down at the server, they log in with their Active Directory credentials, immediately they are logged into a virtual machine on that box and have no way of accessing any of the information on the actual server.

Questions:

Is this possible?

Can you please point me in the direction of a tutorial or give me the proper terminology to be able to Google how to do what I'm trying to do?

If not exactly the above scenario, is there some way to get it close to the same behavior?

Thank you so much for your time and responses in advance!

Comment: Why don't you deploy virtual desktops or remote desktop services for these users?

Comment: Maybe you can use something like "Citrix XenAPP" Terminal Server. But you need Licenses for this...

Comment: You can just replace their Shell (through registry) to be whatever you want or limit their access with some GPO, but both methods, security wise, are a bad idea. There are always loopholes you don't see.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible?

Yes.

Supplementary question:

> Is this a good idea?

No.

> An employee sits down at the server

As a general rule, you don't want your employees sitting down at servers.  It's a waste of servers and employees.

Your question leaves out too much of the why and how for us to guess at your thinking that has led you to this idea, but I'm unable to imagine a scenario where what you propose would be preferred to JoeQwerty's suggestion:

> Why don't you deploy virtual desktops or remote desktop services